# Unexpected token function when running gulp mocha with node 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, mocha.js, gulp-mocha

I'm using gulp to run mocha tests, 
It seems to fail with es7 syntax like async await and stuff, 
I'm using node version 10 in which the async await are supported, 
when I run test with 
`mocha test/sample.js`

it works , when I run the same via gulp it fails with

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Unable to parse /Users/**/**/**/**/media-templates.js

Line 20: Unexpected token function
```

Line 20 in `media-templates.js` looks like below

`mediaTemplate.pre('save', async function () {`

I'm not using any trans compilers like babel as node 10 supports these things.